# PHP Insert Json Array Data as Separate Row in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json, arraylist

I have a json array list as below.I am trying to insert each item as separate row in mysql table

```
 {"order_array":

  [{
   "qty":"1",
   "menu_name":"PARATHA (KAZI FARMS) 20 PCS",
   "sub_total":"265.0"
   },
 
   {
    "qty":"2",
    "menu_name":"PARATHA (KAZI FARMS) 10 PCS",
    "sub_total":"300.0"
   }],
  
  "amount":
         {
          "sub_total":"565.0",
          "discount":"0",
          "wallet":"0",
          "total_price":595,
          "delivery_charges":30           
         }
 }
```

I have written below code but it is not inserting any data

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['json_order_list'], true);

foreach ($data as $row) {
   
   foreach ($array["order_array"] as $row) 
   {
      $item_name = $row['menu_name'];
      $qty = $row["qty"];
      $amount = $row['sub_total'];
      $order_id = '1';
      
      $sql_order = "INSERT INTO tbl_orders (item_name, qty, amount, order_id) 
            VALUES ('$item_name','$qty','$amount','$order_id')";
            
      mysqli_query($link, $sql_order);

    }
 }
```

what's wrong I am doing

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: If you look at the data structure, you will probably find you don't need the first `foreach ($data as $row) {`.

Comment: no error! tried without  foreach ($data as $row) {  but nothing inserted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your data structure nested loop is redundant. You can use next code as solution:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare(
    $link, 
    "INSERT INTO tbl_orders (item_name, qty, amount, order_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"
);
   
foreach ($data["order_array"] as $row) 
{
    $item_name = $row['menu_name'];
    $qty = $row["qty"];
    $amount = $row['sub_total'];
    $order_id = '1';
    
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sddd', $item_name, $qty, $amount, $order_id);
    
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

}
```

Look working code at [PHPize.online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=02804f7f274783bdfc1773b82ab436c4&sqlses=d3f640a76301942ef1bd216be25c34ed&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: Dear @Cid, You absolutely right. I updated my answer.

Comment: Since `$order_id` is hardcoded and static, it should not be passed as a parameter, but written directly into the prepared statement.